# Trapped – you can join a chat room, but you can never leave

Tags: bug, chat, logout

If memory serves correctly, once a user could click on the little upper button and leave a chatroom. That button is shown below:

[image: button]

But recently, I started noticing that this is no longer the case – once you click the button, you check out of the room for a period of time, then Stack Overflow automatically logs you back in after a while.

I understand how chat bugs are as important to SE development team as a neighbourhood stray cat to a dog loving family. But I feel morally obligated to report this, just like I would feel guilty for not telling you there is a hole in your backyard after someone fell into it when we came for a BBQ gathering.

Comment: +1 just for the analogy.

Comment: I'm debating whether to upvote - there's the analogy, but the circle isn't red or freehand.

Comment: -1 because that arrow looks ugly, +2 because BBQs are delicious.

Comment: You should have known this when you signed into the chatroom called "Hotel California".

Comment: There is a link titled "leave", see [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yl9d.png). Just tested and it works just fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Tried that too, not working for me either ... 'leave' is when you inside the room for which you want to quit. Up arrow is when you are in another room and want to quit some hidden chat(s). Neither are working properly.